# Bash script for summary statistics

Tags: bash

I have a `csv` file of customer data and I'd like to find the probability that they buy a product based on past behavior.

The table looks like this:

```
custId         prodId       purchased
   001           0001          0
   002           0001          0
   006           1001          1
   001           0501          0
   012           8001          0
   189           0071          0
   487           0001          1
   ...           ...          ...
```

`custId` is the customer id, `prodId` is the product, neither column is unique nor is `custId-prodId` unique as a customer can be shown the same product multiple times.

The ideal output would be something like:

```
 custId         purchased
   001           .0999
   002           0
   006           1
   012           0
   189           .75
   487           1
   ...          ...
```

I'm looking at doing this in `bash` as the file is too large to fit in memory.

Any suggestions?

Comment: FWIW, I would recommend using Perl or a similar programming language to solve this problem. Bash scripting can be pretty painful, to say the least.

Comment: Bash only supports integer arithmetics. Use a more powerful language (Perl or similar).

Comment: So, you're trying to write the equivalent of the SQL query `SELECT custId, SUM(purchased)/COUNT(1) AS purchased FROM customerData.csv GROUP BY custId ORDER BY custId`?

Comment: @ruakh: yes, except SUM(purchased)/COUNT(purchased), I'm not sure if (1) vs (purchased) matters.

Comment: @screechOwl: `COUNT(purchased)` and `COUNT(1)` are only different if `purchased` is ever `NULL` (in which case `COUNT(1)` includes those rows, whereas `COUNT(purchased)` does not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Jonah Bishop and choroba both comment above that you should use Perl, and I tend to agree, here's a Bash command that uses Perl to do this:

```
perl -e \
  ' use warnings;
    use strict;
    my %custCounts;
    my %custSums;
    while(<>)
    {
      m/^(\d{3}),\d{4},([01])$/
        or die "ruakh doesn'"'"'t understand your CSV file format";
      ++$custCounts{$1};
      ++$custSums{$1} if $2;
    }
    foreach my $custId (sort keys %custCounts)
    {
      print "$custId,", ($custSums{$custId}||0) / $custCounts{$custId}, "\n";
    }
  ' < customerData.csv
```

The above assumes that your CSV file looks like this:

```
001,0001,0
002,0001,0
006,1001,1
001,0501,0
012,8001,0
189,0071,0
487,0001,1
```

with the fields being three digits, four digits, and `0` or `1`, respectively. If that's not the case, then you'll need to adjust the line that starts with `m/`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example using `awk`:

```
awk '{++shown[$1]; if ($3 > 0) ++purchased[$1];}END{for (cust in purchased) print cust, purchased[cust]/shown[cust]}' datafile
```

There's no error checking, so if your input deviates, it'll die; in addition, you'll have to preprocess to remove any headers, etc. If your field separator isn't whitespace, use 'awk -F, ...' to set the field separator to ',' or whatever.

Also, this only prints the entries with non-zero percentages, to include all customers, change `for (cust in purchased)` to `for (cust in shown)`.